# Массив в базу данных. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Мне нужно сохранить более 1 категории в мою колонку БД

```
              @foreach($categories as $category)
                                    <label class="gap-2 col-sm-5">
                                        <input class="form-check-input flex-shrink-0" name="category_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $category->id }}">
                                        <span>{{$category->title}}</span>
                                    </label>
                                @endforeach
```

Колонка в БД называется `category_id`

вот код в миграции, куда надо сохранять массив

```
        Schema::create('servers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('image_avatar')->nullable();
            $table->longText('content');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('invite');
            $table->string('star')->nullable();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('language_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();

            $table->index('language_id','server_language_idx');
            $table->index('category_id','server_category_idx');
            $table->foreign('language_id','server_language_fk')->on('languages')->references('id');
            $table->foreign('category_id','server_category_fk')->on('categories')->references('id');

            $table->timestamps();
```

Итог таков что запись остается ```NULL``
Подскажите где я допустил ошибку, может даже я и еще что-то должен вам скинуть )))

Comment: Причем, когда я делал не checkbox, а обычный select, то все было прекрастно
Но даже щас я не могу добавить 1 категорию в свою колонку БД

Comment: Покажите код сохранения